# Polynomial factors from sum of polynomials with known factors

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, roots, factoring, interpolation

Say I know the linear factors of polynomials A and B.  For instance, if they were cubic I could express them as `A(x) = (ax + b)(cx + d)(ex + f)` and `B(x) = (gx + h)(ix + j)(kx + l)`.  Are there any circumstances under which I can take advantage of knowing these original factors if I want to compute the linear factors of the polynomial A + B?

Comment: I am not sure if this question is specific enough, say for e.g. with disjoint factors like $2\times 5 +3\times3=19$ all we get is what won't be factors of the sum, though if there's common factors that's clearly useful. Is that the sort of thing you're after?

Comment: My specific use case is linearly interpolating between two 3x3 matrices and finding times at which the determinant is zero.  That leads to the sum of six cubic polynomials all of whose original factors are known.  But I am curious about the more general case, even if in this specific case my best option is to solve for the roots of a cubic equation from scratch.

Comment: For context, I'm asking this question as a programmer.  The linear factors will be available to the program when it runs, but they aren't fixed and known to me in advance.  I'm looking for potential algorithmic optimizations - it feels like there should be a way to take advantage of the fact that I know the linear pieces from which the final polynomial has been generated and I want to satisfy or quash that feeling.

Comment: If you know the linear factors of a polynomial and then add a constant, you don't expect to know anything about the new polynomial. I think the only thing that one can say in general is that a common factor of $A$ and $B$ will be a factor of $A+B$, which is obvious.

Comment: Perhaps others can come up with suggestions on your question on factors, however i find factors a multiplication artifact, which does not translate meaningfully well when adding terms in most rings. You may have much better luck addressing your original question instead, for e.g if they are rotation matrices you're interpolating, there are ways such as SLERP to smoothly do that.

Comment: "If you know the linear factors of a polynomial and then add a constant, you don't expect to know anything about the new polynomial." I would accept this as the answer to this question, although it would be great if you could point me toward resources about why this is the case and to what domain(s) of knowledge this result is connected.

Comment: I think this can probably be closed as a repeat with a redirection to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1789320/roots-of-sum-of-two-polynomials-with-known-roots?rq=1
My bad for not identifying it had been previously asked until I saw it in the related questions sidebar!