# Is it possible to obtain roots from the weighted sum of other polynomials in their root form?

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

Given $n$ polynomials $A_1, A_2, .. A_n$with the same degree $M$.

$A_i = \prod_{j=0}^M(1+Q_{ij}x)$.

In their root form $Q$, $Q_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}$. And the function, I'm interested in, $B$ is a weighted sum of $A_i$ with weight $w_i$.

$B = \sum_{i=1}^n w_iA_i$.

$B$ also has it's root form denote $B=\prod_{k=0}^n(1+C_kx)$.

My question is how can I get $C$ efficiently given $Q$ and $w$?

Comment: This is equivalent to finding the roots of $B = \sum w_iA_i$ knowing the roots of $A_i$. There is no direct relation or dependency between the respective sets of roots, efficient or not.

Comment: is there any good reference to  `There is no direct relation or dependency between the respective sets of roots` this claim so that I can learn from it? @dxiv

Comment: See [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1789320/roots-of-sum-of-two-polynomials-with-known-roots) for a counterexample, and [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30072/roots-of-sum-of-two-polynomials) [3](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41473/bounding-the-roots-of-the-sum-of-two-polynomials) for the more general question of bounding the roots of the sum.